# How can I fix error 404 for dropzone in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone

I want to make a gallery for a project with dropzone in Laravel 
but I receive error 404 .. often error 404 happens for wrong route but obviously every thing is right...

but I receive this error

My form:

```
{
< form action="{{url('admin/gallery/upload?='.$project->id)}}" method="post" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
}
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/admin/gallery/upload', 'admin\ProjectController@upload');
```

My function

```
     public function upload(Request $request ,$id){     
        $files=$request->file('file');
        $name=rand()."-".$id.$files->getClientOriginalName();
        $files->move('upload/gallery/'.$id.'/',$name);
        $gallery=new Gallery();
        $gallery->product_id=$id;
        $gallery->url=$name;
        $gallery->save();
    }
```

Comment: The URL is posting to `admin/gallery/upload?='.$project->id` but the route is `/admin/gallery/upload`. Try changing it to `/admin/gallery/upload/*`

Answer (score 0):

URL appears to be mismatched against the route.  Try with a variable in the route for POST instead of the `?=` syntax.

**Form:**

```
< form action="{{url('admin/gallery/upload/'.$project->id)}}" method="post" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('/admin/gallery/upload/{id}', 'admin\ProjectController@upload');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use binding and set name for route for better coding and more readability.

Route:

```
Route::post('/admin/gallery/{project}/upload', 'admin\ProjectController@upload')->name('upload.gallery');
```

Form:

```
<form action="{{ route('upload.gallery',['project'=>$project]) }}" method="post" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
```

Method in Controller:

```
 public function upload(Request $request ,Project $project){

    $files=$request->file('file');
    $name=rand()."-".$id.$files->getClientOriginalName();
    $files->move('upload/gallery/'.$project->id.'/',$name);
    $gallery=new Gallery();
    $gallery->product_id=$project->id;
    $gallery->url=$name;
    $gallery->save();
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't need the project object, just the `id`.  Not worth the overhead of injecting the project model in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If just need id and don't need $project object in feature do this:

Route:

```
Route::post('/admin/gallery/{id}/upload', 'admin\ProjectController@upload')->name('upload.gallery');
```

Form:

```
<form action="{{ route('upload.gallery',['id'=>$project->id]) }}" method="post" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
```

Method in Controller:

```
 public function upload(Request $request ,$id){

    $files=$request->file('file');
    $name=rand()."-".$id.$files->getClientOriginalName();
    $files->move('upload/gallery/'.$id.'/',$name);
    $gallery=new Gallery();
    $gallery->product_id=$id;
    $gallery->url=$name;
    $gallery->save();
}
```